# What exactly is Limit in Dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

From AWS Docs:

> *A single Query operation can retrieve a **maximum of 1 MB** of data*. This limit applies before any FilterExpression or ProjectionExpression
> is applied to the results. *If LastEvaluatedKey is present in the
> response and is non-null, you must paginate the result set*.

I have been working on DynamoDB for sometime now, when I increase limit of a query it would always give me more records. So What's the closest meaning of **Limit = 2**? returning 2 items (or max 1 MB which we know for the fact) right? So, would that make **Limit=1000**; return 1000 items or 1000 MBs of data? Or 1000 records and no effect on data size? Or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `limit` parameter only affects the number of items that are returned.

Limit = 2 means at most 2 items will be returned. The upper limit for the `limit` parameter is 1000 - one API call can't return more than 1000 items.

Depending on the item size, you may not get all the records that you specify with the limit parameter, because at most 1MB of data is read from the table.
That means if all items in your table are 400KB in size each (the max per item) and you set the `limit` parameter to 5, you will always get at most 2 items from the table, because of the 1MB limit.

Comment: Makes sense, accepting it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

In a query, the Limit is the number of items that will be *Shown* after the query (or available in your SDK response).

So if you make a query that normally would return 15 items, but have a limit of 2, you get the first 2 based on their sort key (and if no sort key its the first two that come back, I believe the oldest items, but dont quote me on that.

The 1mb limit is a hard cap of the total size of the return JSON from the query made by the SDK api call. So if you have 100 items and when in a JSON format they exceed 1 mb worth of data, then only the first 1mb worth of entries (whole entries) will be returned. A pagination token will also be returned (NextToken if I recall correctly) that can be used in the next query to start the return from the ending of the previous one (pagination).

Its VERY IMPORTANT to realize that the combination of Limit keyword and 1mb hard cap pagination means that if you have a query that would require pagination, and include a limit, that limit is applied *AFTER* the pagination begins.

So if the first page of your query returns 15 items and you have a limit of 5, you get the first five items. Then if you call next token *you get item 16-20* because the original query, before the limit, had next token assigned to item 16.

In general, there is little reason to use Limit - instead, your Partition Key/Sort Key combination should be set up along your access patterns so you are only retrieving the actual items you need on any given call. Using SortKey expressions of >, <, =, between, starts_with, contains are a better way to limit the number of responses than Limit. The only major use case I can usually find for Limit is literally needing just the latest item of a potential multiple items after a specific date. But even so, its usually better just to take the entire query and get the first item yourself in your code (index 0) instead so you don't accidentally loose items from the limit/query combination.

Comment: Great explanation, was equally helpful as the marked answer, but the marked one was a bit concise so marked for people visiting in future.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that if the limit is set, for example, to 10, it will only scan 10 either from the beginning of the table if `ExclusiveStartKey` is null. If `ExclusiveStartKey` is not null, it will scan 10 keys from the `ExclusiveStartKey's` position. The key word here is 'scan' because it will only filter within those 10 records and return the results. Pagination doesn't work like this in Mongo or MySQL. In those dbs, it filters and skips and then limits. In Dynamodb, it skips, limits, and then filters. That's why it has the `ScannedCount` in the response.